# Problem with the service files and view in Angular

Tags: angular

I built a simple To-Do app in Angular. When the app component inits, it exports an array of todos from service file with the ***getTodos()*** method. We also can add/remove todos. So when we delete a todo, component calls the ***removeTodo()*** method from the exported service. The problem is - when we remove a todo, it is removed from the service file, but not in view. Please help me solve the problem.

Here's my code

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  todos: Todo[] = [];
  todoTitle: string = '';
  todoId: number = 0;
  appTitle: string = 'To-Do App';

  constructor(private transportationService: TransportationService) {
    this.todos = transportationService.getTodos();
  }

  addTodos(): void {
    const todo: Todo = {
      id: ++this.todoId,
      title: this.todoTitle,
    };

    this.transportationService.addTodo(todo);
    this.todoTitle = '';
  }

  removeTodo(id: number): void {
    this.transportationService.removeTodo(id);
  }
}
```

and the service file:

```
  @Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
  })
  export class TransportationService {
    todos: Todo[] = [];

    constructor() {}

    getTodos() {
      return this.todos;
    }

    addTodo(todo: Todo): void {
      this.todos.push(todo);
    }

    removeTodo(id: number): void {
      this.todos = this.todos.filter((i) => i.id !== id);
      console.log(
        this.todos,
        this.todos.filter((i) => i.id !== id)
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: This could be solved nicer in general (using observables) - but in this case, you could probably (not sure) fix this by re-setting this.todos in your component after you have removed removeTodo(id: number): void {
    this.transportationService.removeTodo(id);
    this.todos = this.transportationService.getTodos();
  }

Comment: @MikeOne You should post an answer, it will work

Comment: Thanks a lot @MikeOne, it works, but I would want to solve it with another way. Is it possible ?

Comment: Sure. @faisal gave a fine answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Observable` along with `BahaviorSubject` to correctly implement your scenario. This would asynchronously update the `todos`. The `AppComponent` would become this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  todos$: Observable<Todo[]> = this.transportationService.todos$.asObservable();
  
  todoTitle: string = '';
  todoId: number = 0;
  appTitle: string = 'To-Do App';

  constructor(private transportationService: TransportationService) { }

  addTodo(): void {
    const todo: Todo = {
      id: ++this.todoId,
      title: this.todoTitle,
    };

    this.transportationService.addTodo(todo);
    this.todoTitle = '';
  }

  removeTodo(id: number): void {
    this.transportationService.removeTodo(id);
  }
}
```

... and your `TransportationService` would become this:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs";
import { Todo } from "./todo.model";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class TransportationService {
  /** An observable of todos */
  todos$: BehaviorSubject<Todo[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);

  /** Internal todos. */
  private _todos: Todo[] = [];

  constructor() {}

  /** Use for statically getting todos. */
  getTodos() {
    return this._todos;
  }

  /** Adds the given todo. */
  addTodo(todo: Todo): void {
    this._todos.push(todo);
    this.todos$.next(this._todos);
  }

  /** Removes a todo by given id. */
  removeTodo(id: number): void {
    this._todos = this._todos.filter((i) => i.id !== id);
    this.todos$.next(this._todos);
  }
}
```

I have quickly created a [**demo on StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-c26qr7?file=src/app/transportation.service.ts) which you can have a look at.

Answer (score -2):

You should make change in the todo array. A simple filtering based on id
would be fine.

This should be done in the app.component also.